# ChartJS multichart graph not showing correctly legends

Tags: charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Am trying to create bar graph with multiple plots using chartjs and the graph is generated successfully but one of the legend is not showing correctly.
Am using Chartjs 2.9.3 version.

One of the bar legendary is showing as circle instead of rectangle box. Kindly let me know if any workaround to get the correct legendary.

Bar graph show circle in the legendary

[image]

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',

        data: {
            
            datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Label1',
                data: [3,4],
                type: 'scatter',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                pointStyle:'circle',
                pointRadius:5
            },        
            {
                label: 'Label2',
                data: [1,2],
                type: 'scatter',
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                pointStyle:'triangle',
                pointRadius:5
            },
            {
                backgroundColor: 'grey',
                label: 'Label3',
                data: [1,2],
                borderWidth: 1,
                type: 'bar'
                
            }
            
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive:false,
            legend: {
                labels : {
                    usePointStyle: true
                }
            },
            title:      {
                display: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{                   
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: '$/MWh'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `usePointstyle` flag is set in the legend it defaults to the circle. In V2 this is not configurable for bar charts so you have 2 options

You can switch to a [html legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) and style that. Or you can update to chart.js version 3 where you can configure it for bar charts:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        pointStyle: 'rect'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```